# Using a Linked Server to import data from Excel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have read a lot about linked servers being bad when there are multiple hops across servers and distributed joins.

What if I am just using a linked server to import data into SQL Server from an Excel spreadsheet?

What if that's *all* I am doing and the rest is being all done in SQL Server itself on a single server?

I want to avoid SSIS owing to headaches with multiple transactions and chaining them to each other (which is failing for some reason).

Comment: Why not investigate that "some reason" instead? SSIS is the suggested way to import/export data to/from SQL Server. Linked Servers have security/stability and performance issues. They're actually good for transfering small amounts of data and perform distributed transactions in T-SQL.

Comment: Thank you, that is true, I am looking into that too. I have described in a bit more detail below as a comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Import wizard to load your data.  The **Import/Export wizard actually uses SSIS** to do the work.  But if your goal is to avoid learning SSIS, then just do not save the package.

[Simple way to import data into SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/)

That MSSQLtips article walks you through setting up the import and then run the data into your SQL Server destination.

If you want to reuse the package (which is probably a good idea) there is a **save** option that allows you to save the SSIS package that was internally generated and use it again and again.

However, if the **Linked Server** approach is the way you want to go, there is a tutorial here:

[Excel Import to SQL Server using Linked Servers](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-linked-servers.htm)

This is somewhat more complex to set up, but should work OK.

**UPDATE:** based on your comment about coordinating two transactions you might find it simpler to import the data into two staging tables.  (You would **most likely truncate** those tables before each load.) The table `Stage01` receives one load and the table `Stage02` receives the other load.

Then, now that both data sets are in their own tables, you can join between `Stage01` and `Stage02` data sets to insert the resolved data into your operational database tables. This would likely simplify the processing of the two data sets.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful answers. I am just not able to get two transactions to relate to each other in SSIS. One completes and the other dependent transaction does not. I wanted there to be dependency between both transaction containers. So I was thinking of setting everything up using SQL job agent rather than rely on SSIS solely for this.

Comment: A SQL Agent job is a good mechanism for ensuring that a repeating task happens on a schedule.   A suggestion added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will go with that. Will avoid SSIS and schedule it using SQL Job Agent.